# Cannot get Visual Editor to install on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, visual-editor

I am getting this error:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem,2.0.300.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem_2.0.300.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo,2.0.300.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo_2.0.300.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo.vm,2.0.200.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo.vm_2.0.200.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo.vm.common,2.0.201.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo.vm.common_2.0.201.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.proxy,2.0.201.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.proxy_2.0.201.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.source,1.4.0.v20090826-1446-7H-FPbAcggQleH8hJifHfUd.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.source_1.4.0.v20090826-1446-7H-FPbAcggQleH8hJifHfUd.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.ui,2.0.100.R3_0_4.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.ui_2.0.100.R3_0_4.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.util,2.0.200.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.util_2.0.200.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.workbench,2.0.201.R3_1_maintenance.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.jem.workbench_2.0.201.R3_1_maintenance.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve,1.4.0.v20090826-1446.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve_1.4.0.v20090826-1446.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve.cde,1.4.0.v20090826-1446.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve.cde_1.4.0.v20090826-1446.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve.doc,1.4.0.v20090826-1446.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve.doc_1.4.0.v20090826-1446.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve.java.core,1.4.0.v20090826-1446.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve.java.core_1.4.0.v20090826-1446.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve.propertysheet,1.4.0.v20090826-1446.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve.propertysheet_1.4.0.v20090826-1446.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve.sdk,1.4.0.v20090826-1446.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve.sdk_1.4.0.v20090826-1446.jar
  Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ve.source,1.4.0.v20090826-1446-777N-CcNBC0BwNk5HZZk.
  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ve/updates/1.4/plugins/org.eclipse.ve.source_1.4.0.v20090826-1446-777N-CcNBC0BwNk5HZZk.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a VE (Visual Editor) installation on a fresh eclipse3.5 setup, with a clean empty workspace, to be sure.
(Or at least remove the directories "`org.eclipse.jem.beaninfo`" et "`org.eclipse.ve.java.core`" from "`<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins`".

Download  the [all-in-one update site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/ve/downloads/drops/1.4.0/R200909301124/VE-Update-1.4.0.zip) (zip file), unzip it and then reference it as an Update site in the "Available Software Site" preference page.
From there the installation should be able to proceed successfully.

Comment: I tried both those options with no luck.  The all in one zip doesn't even contain JAR's in the plugin directory ... it contains `.jar.pack.gz` files.  The updater reports it can't find the necessary jar's.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading & installing this plugin from Soyatec ... http://www.soyatec.org/update/Ganymede/org.eclipse.ve_1.4.0.v20080528.zip